# Load balancing in node server

Tags: node.js, apache, architecture, load-balancing, pm2

I have created a node server using express. I using this architecture as follows:
-> I am serving node port as proxy on domain using apache.
-> I am using pm2 for handling node process. I have created two cluster and ran individually on different cores. (http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/cluster-mode/)

My question is

1. Am i doing this correct way as production standard?
2. Do i need load balancing on apache level? because clusters will come
       in picture after apache?

Am i correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's correct architecture.

But Nginx and Pm2 go more hand in hand. Apache is okay too.